# I get the same text my first id in all my tooltips, even though it doesn't belong to that id

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to learn some Javascript, and combine it with PHP and HTML. For the moment, I'm having the problem that when I mouseover my second or third div, It'll write whatever I'm having in the first div.

```
    $posts = get_posts(((isset($_GET['id'])) ? $_GET['id'] : null));

    foreach($posts as $post){
    ?>
        <div onmouseover="fixad()" onmouseout="tabort()" style="background-color:red; width:100px;"><?php echo $post['user'] . " " . $post['contents'] . "<br>";?></div><br>
        <div id="popup" style="display:block; background-color:black; width:100px; height:100px; color:white; float:right;"><?php echo $post['date_posted'] .  " " . $post['user']; ?></div>
    <?php
    } ?>
```

My get_posts function looks like this:

```
    function get_posts($id = null) {
      $posts = array();
      $query = "select contents, user, date_posted FROM database where id=$'id'";
      $query = mysql_query($query);
      while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $posts[] = $row;
      }
      return $posts;
    }
```

My Javascript is simple and looks like this:

```
    function fixad() {
      var r = document.GetElementById("popup");
      r.style.display = "block";
    }

    function tabort(){
      var r = document.GetElementById("popup");
      r.style.display = "none";
    }
```

To summarize it: I want to write out text where id = 5 in 1 div. But I get text from id = 5 when it's supposed to be from another id.

So my

```
    <div id="popup"<?php echo $post['id'];?></div>
```

Will print out the same id on every popup.

I'm sorry if this was confusing, I'll can elaborate if you want.

Comment: Your `get_posts` returns data? Look here `select contents,user, date_posted FROM database where id=$'id'` Also, here `$post = $posts =`

Comment: Yes, the function works fine. Here is a gif. http://gyazo.com/95a8ca36df71812cbd8a2662d233b60a

As you can see, when I mouseover the first div, I see data from id = 3. When I mouseover the second div, I see the same.

Comment: That query can't be returning data. The dollar sign is on the wrong side of the quote. Is this copy and pasted? I'd expect your query throws a `1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax`. Well aside from the errors mentioned all your elements have the same `id`.

Comment: You are correct, I just took a small piece from my code. I have more code and everything works. Sorry for the misunderstanding. [Better gif.](http://gyazo.com/ec5f0cc365a97bcb414d1684cce69da9)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your elements have the same id. So `document.GetElementById("popup");` gets the first element every time. Ids should be unique. I'd pass the id of each post back with `posts` then put that in with the id so each div can be identified correctly.

```
<div id="popup"
```

to:

```
<div id="popup' . $id . '"
```

Comment: Alright, it wont react but at least I know what I've been searching for. I dont know how to create unique id's.

Comment: Have you considered doing this with jQuery? I find jQuery much easier to work with, my JS skills also lack.

Comment: I have not. I'm fairly new to javascript and have no experience in jQuery what so ever. If you know any decent guide, I'll be glad to check it through. I'm very happy that you've been helping me

Comment: Here's a link on how to use their class selector, https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/, and id selector, http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/ I think those would be useful for you here.